# Hide Text dynamically

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic, gui-construction

I have a graphic, with on the left a `PopupMenu`, a `Rectangular`, a `Text` and a `Button`.

If the value of the `PopupMenu` is right/wrong, after pressing the button, the `Rectangular` become green/red and the `Text` become right/wrong.

```
Labeled[listar1 = {PopupMenu[Dynamic[r1], {"Sen","Cos","Tan"}]};
         Plot[Sin[x],{x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle->Red,PlotRange->{-4,4},ImageSize->Large],
         Column[Flatten[{{Text["What function?"],listar1},
         Graphics[{Dynamic[If[r2,Green,Red]], Rectangle[{0, 0}]},ImageSize->{20,20}],
         Graphics[Text[Style[Dynamic[If[r2,"Right!","Wrong!"]],Medium]],ImageSize->{100,30}],
         Button["Check",r2=(r1==="Sen")]}]],Right];
```

How can I set the default color of the `Rectangular` (Blue for example)?

And also, how can I hide the `Text` at the beginning with no string showed?

Comment: `If` takes a third argument for neither true nor false. Use that. e.g. `If[r2, Green, Red, Blue]` and `If[r2, "Right!", "Wrong!", ""]`.

Comment: @MB1965 It doesn't work: the rectangular has still the last color and the text also.
There is only a new empty entry in the popupmenu

Comment: Where are you using that? Are you adding the third argument to the `If` calls you have? I should note it works for me (just tried it).

Comment: @MB1965 Labeled[listar1 = {PopupMenu[Dynamic[r1], {"Sen","Cos","Tan"}]};
         Plot[Sin[x],{x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle->Red,PlotRange->{-4,4},ImageSize->Large],
         Column[Flatten[{{Text["What function?"],listar1},
         Graphics[{Dynamic[If[r2,Green,Red,Blue]], Rectangle[{0, 0}]},ImageSize->{20,20}],
         Graphics[Text[Style[Dynamic[If[r2,"Right!","Wrong!",""]],Medium]],ImageSize->{100,30}],
         Button["Check",r2=(r1==="Sen")]}]],Right];

Comment: Also if you're adding the text outside of the `Graphics` you don't need a `Text` and `Graphics` wrapper on it.

Comment: that should work. Have you cleared `r1` and `r2` before testing?

Comment: @MB1965 no, it was that, thank you.

Comment: See my answer for how you can use `DynamicModule` to get around that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try. I wrapped it in [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html) to localize `r1` and `r2`:

```
DynamicModule[{r1, r2},
 Labeled[
  listar1 = {PopupMenu[Dynamic[r1], {"Sen", "Cos", "Tan"}]};
  Plot[Sin[x],
   {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {-4, 4},
   ImageSize -> Large
   ], Column[
   Flatten[{{Text["What function?"], listar1}, 
     Graphics[{Dynamic[If[r2, Green, Red, Blue]], Rectangle[{0, 0}]}, 
      ImageSize -> {20, 20}],
     Dynamic[If[r2, "Right!", "Wrong!", ""]],
     Button["Check", r2 = (r1 === "Sen")]}]
   ],
  Right]
 ]
```

Before:
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]